# Set working in file but not in .vimrc

Tags: vim

When I put `set scroll=10` in my `.vimrc` it does not work, but it does work when I enter the command in command mode.

I have many other commands in my `.vimrc`, what reason could there be for this `set` to not be getting through? It is the last line in my `.vimrc`.

Comment: Are you using any plugins that may override this setting?

Answer (score 3):

```
:verbose set scroll?
```

should tell you which plugin script has last modified that option. If you don't find the culprit this way, you could workaround by setting it at the last possible moment by putting this in your `~/.vimrc`

```
:autocmd VimEnter * set scroll=10
```